# ./helm init --service-account=tiller not working on GCP for creating a tiller service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

1. I installed Helm on GCP using:

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.14.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

2. I unzipped the file in Cloud Shell using:

```
tar zxfv helm-v2.14.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
cp linux-amd64/helm .
```

3. I then added a cluster administrator in cluster's RBAC to give Jenkins permission in cluster using:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=$(gcloud config get-value account)
```

4. Then granted tiller the server side of helm using:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=$(gcloud config get-value account)
```

5. Then I had to ensure Helm(tiller) is properly installed using:

```
./helm init --service-account=tiller
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> $HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/student_03_c54e335b6eb9/.helm.
> Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you also need to create the 'tiller' service account and the 'clusterrolebinding' for that service account. The three commands would look like this:

> kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system

> kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

> helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -